# Prevent a user from exiting from firefox using js

Tags: javascript

how can I prevent user exit firefox?
I want that user woldn`t leave page before all required fields are filled.
I would be happy to see full example...
Thanks

Comment: You can't.  How far would you take this?  At the end of the day, they can always pull the power cord out.

Comment: You can show a confirmation message using `onbeforeunload`, but thats it. Anyway its a bad idea trying to prevent user from exiting.

Comment: May be you need to put it other way around. If you could tell the reason that **what made you think this way?** then you might get better response!

Answer (score 2):

You can't stop someone from closing the browser, or navigating away from the page, if that's what they want to do.  It's *their* browser - you can't force them to do anything.

That said, you *can* pop up a message by hooking the [`onbeforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) and returning a string if there are still actions you want them to perform.  Most browsers will then display this string in a dialog asking whether they really do want to navigate away (or close the browser etc), however [the Firefox devs have taken the stance](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641509) that that is a security risk and will only present a generic message instead.  Even with this in place, the user can still choose to close the browser or navigate away.